# How to parse <strxml>String</strxml> using soap?

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

This is my SOAP webservice.i have donn. Bt it got error.This is my code.Can anyone help me.how to parse  string in android.
      int
      string
      int
      int
      string
      string
    
Thanks in advance.

```
public boolean callwebservice() {

    boolean result = false;
    int patid = 1;
    String xml = "";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    request.addProperty("PatientId", patid);

    request.addProperty("AppointMentDate", appdate);
    request.addProperty("TimeFrom", apptimeto);
    request.addProperty("TimeTo", appfrom);
    request.addProperty("ReasonForAppointMent", appreason);
    request.addProperty("strxml", xml);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    httpTransport.debug = true;
    try {

        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        httpTransport
                .setXmlVersionTag("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>");
        // SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

        System.out.println("myApp" + response.toString());
        System.out.println("response" + response);

        if (response.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
            result = true;

        }

    } catch (SocketException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error : " + "Error on soapPrimitiveData() "
                + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error : " + "Error on soapPrimitiveData() "
                + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: i  have already do login using soap.bt that after when redirect to appointment i got error.my que is how to get response in xml.

Answer (score 0):

First import ksoap2 library to your project and try this.[Here is the link](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/downloads/detail?name=ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar&can=2&q=)

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/";
private final String URL = "http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webserviceX.NET/ConversionRate";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "ConversionRate";
SoapObject request;
String weight;
String fromUnit;
String toUnit;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

    weight = "USD";
    fromUnit = "INR";
    toUnit = "Kilograms";

    PropertyInfo weightProp =new PropertyInfo();
    weightProp.setName("FromCurrency");
    weightProp.setValue(weight);
    weightProp.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(weightProp);

    PropertyInfo fromProp =new PropertyInfo();
    fromProp.setName("ToCurrency");
    fromProp.setValue(fromUnit);
    fromProp.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(fromProp);



    //calling the AsyncTask
    new Task().execute();


}
class Task extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    SoapPrimitive response;
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        try {
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
            Log.i("myApp", ""+response);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView tv = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
        tv.setText("1"+weight+" equals "+response.toString()+ " "+fromUnit);
        tv.setTextSize(50);
        setContentView(tv);
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}